# Error: The function either returned None or ended without a return statement. but not found where?

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

I am trying to update my database data based on data submitted from the form a user fills out, but I am receiving this **error**:

> [TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.]

**Error Stack Trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\thanaphonsae\PycharmProjects\Kudson\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "C:\Users\thanaphonsae\PycharmProjects\Kudson\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
        response = self.handle_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\thanaphonsae\PycharmProjects\Kudson\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\thanaphonsae\PycharmProjects\Kudson\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
        raise value
      File "C:\Users\thanaphonsae\PycharmProjects\Kudson\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\thanaphonsae\PycharmProjects\Kudson\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1816, in full_dispatch_request
        return self.finalize_request(rv)
      File "C:\Users\thanaphonsae\PycharmProjects\Kudson\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1831, in finalize_request
        response = self.make_response(rv)
      File "C:\Users\thanaphonsae\PycharmProjects\Kudson\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1957, in make_response
        'The view function did not return a valid response. The'
    TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

This is my **HTML form**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<center>
<tbody>

<table id="myTable" class="table table-sm" cellspacing="0">
<form action ="{{ url_for('editid',id=rows[0])}}" method="POST">

    <h1>ร้านสาขา {{rows[2]}}</h1>

    ผลการแก้ไขข้อมูล: {{ msg }}

<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr class="header active">
        <th scope="col"><input name="date" value="{{rows[1]}}"></th>
        <th scope="col">PMA</th>
        <th scope="col">UPSD</th>
        <th scope="col">BPSD</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <th scope="row">เช้า</th>
        <td>62</td>
        <td><input name="mo_62_upsd" value="{{rows[3]}}"></td>
        <td><input name="mo_62_bpsd" value="{{rows[4]}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">เช้า</th>
        <td>87</td>
        <td><input name="mo_87_upsd" value="{{rows[5]}}"></td>
        <td><input name="mo_87_bpsd" value="{{rows[6]}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">บ่าย</th>
        <td>62</td>
        <td><input name="af_62_upsd" value="{{rows[7]}}"></td>
        <td><input name="af_62_bpsd" value="{{rows[8]}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">บ่าย</th>
        <td>87</td>
        <td><input name="af_87_upsd" value="{{rows[9]}}"></td>
        <td><input name="af_87_bpsd" value="{{rows[10]}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">ดึก</th>
        <td>62</td>
        <td><input name="ev_62_upsd" value="{{rows[11]}}"></td>
        <td><input name="ev_62_bpsd" value="{{rows[12]}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">ดึก</th>
        <td>87</td>
        <td><input name="ev_87_upsd" value="{{rows[13]}}"></td>
        <td><input name="ev_87_bpsd" value="{{rows[14]}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
<center>
    <td width="50%"><input type="submit" value="submit"/></td>
    <tr></tr>
    <td><a href = "/kudson/update">กลับหน้าหลัก</a></td>
</center>
    </tbody>
</form>
</table>
</center>
</html>
```

and this is my **Python route code**:

```
@app.route('/kudson/edit/<id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def editid(id):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            pass
        else:
            try:
                id = request.form['no']
                date = request.form['date']
                mo_62_upsd = request.form['mo_62_upsd']
                mo_62_bpsd = request.form['mo_62_bpsd']
                mo_87_upsd = request.form['mo_87_upsd']
                mo_87_bpsd = request.form['mo_87_bpsd']
                af_62_upsd = request.form['af_62_upsd']
                af_62_bpsd = request.form['af_62_bpsd']
                af_87_upsd = request.form['af_87_upsd']
                af_87_bpsd = request.form['af_87_bpsd']
                ev_62_upsd = request.form['ev_62_upsd']
                ev_62_bpsd = request.form['ev_62_bpsd']
                ev_87_upsd = request.form['ev_87_upsd']
                ev_87_bpsd = request.form['ev_87_bpsd']


            with sql.connect(con_string) as con:

                cur = con.cursor()

                params = date, mo_62_upsd, mo_62_bpsd, mo_87_upsd, mo_87_bpsd, af_62_upsd, af_62_bpsd, af_87_upsd, af_87_bpsd, ev_62_upsd, ev_62_bpsd, ev_87_upsd, ev_87_bpsd, id

                cur.execute("""UPDATE kudson_shift_daily_sell 
                                SET date=?, mo_62_upsd = %s, mo_62_bpsd = %s, mo_87_upsd = %s, mo_87_bpsd = %s, af_62_upsd = %s, af_62_bpsd = %s, af_87_upsd = %s, af_87_bpsd = %s, ev_62_upsd = %s, ev_62_bpsd = %s, ev_87_upsd = %s, ev_87_bpsd = %s 
                                WHERE id = %s""", params)
                con.commit()
                msg = "แก้ไขข้อมูลสำเร็จ"


            return render_template("kudson_edit.html", msg=msg)

        except Exception as e:

            return render_template("kudson_edit.html", msg=e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm sorry if code is not looking clean, I am a newbie at coding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your `POST` response isn't valid. As @Shinra pointed out you just execute `pass` in your POST handler and this **isn't a valid HTTP response**. This happens because when your form executes it has been directed to your `editid` route:

```
<form action ="{{ url_for('editid',id=rows[0])}}" method="POST">
```

Then your '`editid`' route is set up to handle both `POST` and `GET` routes:

```
@app.route('/kudson/edit/<id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
```

but your `POST` route doesn't return a valid HTTP response:

```
def editid(id):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            pass
```

You need to decide what you want to do with this form data when it's submitted. You probably want to validate it, save it on the database, and return an appropriate redirect view based on the above mentioned actions.

Comment: Quick note - my call actually failed in my form.validate() command. I'm not sure how flask knows, but it REQUIRES that something be returned after it takes whatever validate action it's supposed to take (i.e. you must have a return not only within the form.validate() if statement but also after it)

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a `POST` request, the problem is that you don't return anything at all, you just have a `pass`, the code keeps running but there's nothing else to do or return and the function is exited without returning an accepted value. You must return a valid HTTP response.